# Save to file with special characters

Tags: java, intellij-idea, special-characters, writetofile

My program works fine in my MAC, but when I try it on WINDOWS all the special characters turns into %$&.. I am norwegian so the special characters is mostly æøå.

This is the code I use to write to file:

```
    File file = new File("Notes.txt");
    if (file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()) {
        try(PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Notes.txt", true)))) {

            pw.println("");
            pw.println("*****");
            pw.println(notat.getId());
            pw.println(notat.getTitle());
            pw.println(notat.getNote());
            pw.println(notat.getDate());

            pw.close();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            //Did not find file
        }
    } else {
        //Did not find file
    }
```

Now how can I assure that the special characters gets written correct in both OS?

NOTE: I use IntelliJ, and my program is a .jar file.

Comment: Hei! What do you use to view your file after it has been written (on Windows)? It sounds like a disagreement on character set. If so, either your Java program uses the wrong character set for Winodws, or your viewer does. I see nothing wrong with your Java code in this respect.

Comment: Just any text editor, open office, notepad.. anything

Comment: Strange … Is there a Windows expert in the room? :-)

Comment: @OleV.V. Can this problem occur when saved to a txt file? Do you think it can it be solved by saving to e rich txt file, rtf?

Comment: Your text editor is bad at guessing the right charset. Start your java programm with `-Dfile.encoding=CP1252`. This is the default windows chartset (in europe).

Comment: @Peter Where should I put this line? In the Main method? iml or xml file?

Comment: I guess your are starting the app using `IDEA`? If so, put that line into the `VM options:` of the appropriate run/debug configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you use the same encoding on windows as you do on mac.

`IDEA` displays the encoding in the right lower corner. Furthermore, you can configure the encoding `Settings -> Editor -> File Encodings`. 
It's possible to configure the encoding project wide or per file.

Furthermore, read [java default file encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding) to make sure, reading and writing files will always use the same charset.